# How to return non-empty rows for a given ID - Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a table X

> ```
>     ID    A     B
>     --------------
>     1    abc    27
>     1     -     28
>     2     -     33
>     3    xyz    41
>     3     -     07
> ```

I need output as

> ```
>     ID    A     B
>     --------------
>     1    abc    27
>     2     -     33
>     3    xyz    41
> ```

I tried doing

```
max(A) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) as the_value
```

but it did not work. I can still see all the rows in the output table.

I was wondering if somebody has come across a similar situation and has a solution to this ?

Comment: I am not sure i understood you. your title does not reflect what you want - ID=2 in your needed output is '-'

Comment: '-' is to represent null value in the row :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this simple trick for getting the full record for which some column is maxed:

```
select original.* from
(select ID,max(B) as B from Tbl group by ID ) maxB
inner join
(select * from Tbl ) original
on original.ID = maxB.ID and original.B = maxB.B
```

now this is of course an overkill code. you can also do:

```
select Tbl.* from
(select ID,max(B) as B from Tbl group by ID ) maxB
inner join
Tbl
on Tbl.ID = maxB.ID and Tbl.B = maxB.B
```

but the first version is more of a template to do whatever you want with further columns, fields, conditions joins etc.

Comment: Yes. this worked. I wanted to achive this without a join so I  was exploring to see if I can do it using the Analytic UDFs. Thank you Zahiro !